# What is the benefit of the exponential function inside softmax?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, loss-function, softmax

I know that softmax is:

$$ softmax(x) = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_j^n e^{x_j}}$$

This is an $\mathbb{R}^n \implies \mathbb{R}^n$ function, and the elements of the output add up to 1. I understand that the purpose of normalizing is to have elements of $x$ represent probabilities of each class (in classification).

However, I don't understand why we need to take the $exp(x_i)$ of each element, instead of just normalizing:

$$ softmax(x) = \frac{x_i}{\sum_j^n x_j}$$

Which should achieve similar output, especially since both functions seem differentiable and could represent probability outcomes.

Could you tell me:

- What is the advantage of the exponential function inside?
- When should one be used over the other?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is that what you are exactly looking for but for the sake of curiosity there is some other intuitions [here](https://youtu.be/Z1pcTxvCOgw?t=1202) (about 2 or 3 minutes) which from my belief can provide you some information on what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the softmax is applied to *logits* (you can consider them as
unnormalized log-probabilities), which are the output of the neural net. The logits are *unbounded*, i.e. they lie in $(-\infty, \infty)$, so taking the $\exp$ of them would result in positive values which are further normalized to sum to one.

In principle, you can avoid to exponentiate when the neural net's output is strictly positive but I don't know if that would be dentrimental at the gradient level, i.e. when backpropagating the loss.